# Add a Copyright and a title in a latex paper

Tags: ieeetran, copyright

I wonder how I could add the IEEE copyright notice in the bottom centre and the conference title at the upper right hand corner in a LateX paper, with thanks.

Comment: by IEEE copyright notice do you mean the one you get using `\IEEEpubid` when using the `IEEEtran` document class?

Comment: I tried many times adding this form to my IEEE paper but with no use because the conference stile makes disable to copyright notice and conference title.

Comment: Yes the `conference` option disables headings and copyright. If you tell us why you need the copyright anyway we may be able to help.

Comment: Because I have an IEEE conference in Australia and they have told each author to add a conference title to the upper right hand corner in font size 9pt and a copyright notice in font size 10pt at the bottom centre of the paper.

Comment: See my edit to the answer for a patch

Answer (score 1):

In section IV.D of the [`IEEEtran` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf)
you can find the details on how to use `\IEEEpubid`.
IV.C explains `\markboth` for running headers.

The `conference` class option disables both though.

A fix for `\markboth` is to issue

```
\makeatletter
\def\@oddfoot{\hbox{}\hfil \scriptsize \thepage}
\def\@evenfoot{\hbox{}\hfil \scriptsize \thepage}
\makeatother
```

in your preamble.
You can change the contents of the first `hbox` to suit your needs.

If you are *not* using the `conference` option you can do

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\title{Some good old Lipsum}

\author{%
  \IEEEauthorblockN{Lip Sum}\\
  \IEEEauthorblockA{%
    University of Dolor\\
    lipsum@dolor.ac.uk}
  }
\IEEEpubid{0000--0000/00\$00.00~\copyright~2012 IEEE}
\markboth{Journal of Quantum Telecommunications, Vol. 1, No. 1, January 2025}{Shell \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: A Novel Tin Can Link}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\lipsum
\IEEEpubidadjcol
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

As documented in the manual, the `conference` class option disables both `\markboth` and `\IEEEpubid`.